# Does update of a TLB entry leverage the data cache?

Tags: arm, cpu-cache, tlb, page-tables

In ARM CPU architecture, we know that if a TLB cache misses CPU will lookup the page table to compute the physical address of the required virtual address. My question is that if the page table is cached in the data cache area, does CPU use the page table in the cache or the page table in the DRAM when computing the physical address?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, on a TLB miss CPU does a page table walk in MMU which has the page table or a subset of it.

Answer (score 0):

The hardware page table walker sends regular memory requests just like load instructions. Therefore, they pass through the cache hierarchy and page table entries may get cached in the data caches at any level of the cache hierarchy (in general). The OS is responsible for maintaining coherence between the data caches and the TLB.